# Python json.loads() how to handle unescaped quote in string

Tags: python, json, parsing, quote

I am trying to parse json obtained form a site that contains various song names.

One of the song's name is `(Original 12" Instrumental)`

This creates a problem when I try to load the data as JSON, as there is an unescaped quote in the string.

Another example

```
[{
  "example1": "bad song" name",
  "example2": "good song\" name",
}]
```

Anyone has some suggestions to parse the data?

Comment: That is non valid json, and the error is in how you have created it. If you were to save it using json.dump for example it would surely sanitize the `"` with a slash as such: `\"`. Can you recreate the json or the question is "how do I sanitize malformed json?"

Comment: You should get a traceback with an offset, maybe that allows you to find the offending unescaped quotation mark. Check the exception for attributes.

Comment: Indeed. This is not following the guidelines. I obtain this using requests.get(), as this is obtained from a certain site. :(

Comment: As you are using json.loads() you get a string as input. There is no other way than parsing the string and replacing the quotation mark.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I think you can get away with parsing out the (key, value) pairs and escaping the unescaped quotes (while leaving the escaped ones alone).  In other words, you need to search for quotes within the value section that don't have a preceding backslash, then add one.  Regular expressions handle this well:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3

import re, json

s = """
[{
  "example1": "bad song" name",
  "example2": "good song\\" name",
  "example3": {
    "example3a": "another bad song" name",
    "example4b": "another good song\\" name",
  },
}]
"""

def try_to_parse(s):
    try:
        json.loads(s)
        print ("All good")
    except:
        print ("Whoops")

def escape_unescaped_quotes(matchobj):
    (name,val) = matchobj.groups()
    val = re.sub(r'([^\\])"',r'\1\\"', val)
    return '"%s": "%s",' % (name, val)

def get_rid_of_trailing_comma(s):
    return re.sub(r',(\s+)}',r'\1}',s)


print ("Original:",s)
try_to_parse(s)

s = re.sub(r'"(.+)":\s+"(.+)",',escape_unescaped_quotes, s)
s = get_rid_of_trailing_comma(s)

print ("Fixed:",s)
try_to_parse(s)
```

Output:

```
Original: 
[{
  "example1": "bad song" name",
  "example2": "good song\" name",
  "example3": {
    "example3a": "another bad song" name",
    "example4b": "another good song\" name",
  },
}]

Whoops

Fixed: 
[{
  "example1": "bad song\" name",
  "example2": "good song\" name",
  "example3": {
    "example3a": "another bad song\" name",
    "example4b": "another good song\" name"
  }
}]

All good
```